# Pass string with $ into Powershell script parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script called script.ps1

It takes in a parameter called `-myString` and `-myOut`.

How can I pass in a string like `$Test` into `-myString` correctly?

I've tried

```
script.ps1 -myString '$test1' -myOut 3
script.ps1 -myString "$test1" -myOut 3
```

but both just assume that $test is another parameter name, and I miss out on the -myOut

edit: backticks are not showing up in SO, but I am including them.

Edit2:

```
param (
  [string]$myString= “”, 
  [string]$myOut= “”
)

Write-Host "Hello $myString $myOut"
```

Example execution:

```
Script.ps1 -myString ‘$test’ -myOut 3
```

Can’t recall exact output but it’s something like:
Hello 3

Comment: Correct way is to use single quotes `'$test1'` - can you show your script? Remember to share only [mcve].

Comment: What did you mean about backticks? You shouldn't need any of those here. Backticks aren't used in PowerShell except as a line-continuation metacharacter...

Comment: @robdy updated.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Please use first `cat script.ps1` to display the content of script, execute it and then paste **full output** into your question (with proper formatting as mklement0 mentioned). I'm still unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double-quotes if you escape the `$` with a single backtick in front of it:  `` -myString "`$test1" ``.

But the usual approach would be to use single quotes: `-myString '$test1'`.

Note that the single-quoted version should have two identical straight apostrophes (`'`) on either side of the string value, NOT backticks (`` ` ``).

For either the double- or single-quoted version, you *can* use the curly Unicode quotation-mark characters (the same ones that SmartQuotes provides in Word), but those will only work if your session is running with a locale setting that Powershell recognizes as Unicode. If there's a locale mismatch, Windows won't interpret such quotation marks (or any other non-ASCII characters) properly.

So, assuming the punctuation you use matches your session's text encoding, these approaches should work for you as they do for me here:

```
PS /> type foo.ps1 # the test script
param($myString, $myOut)    
Write-Host "myString=$myString, myOut=$myOut"

PS /> ./foo.ps1 -myString "`$test1" -myOut 3 # ASCII double-quotes
myString=$test1, myOut=3

PS /> ./foo.ps1 -myString “`$test1” -myOut 3 # Unicode double-quotes
myString=$test1, myOut=3

PS /> ./foo.ps1 -myString '$test1' -myOut 3 # ASCII single-quotes 
myString=$test1, myOut=3

PS /> ./foo.ps1 -myString ‘$test1’ -myOut 3 # Unicode single-quotes
myString=$test1, myOut=3
```

Note that regardless of which style of double-quotes you use, the backtick for escaping the dollar sign always has to be an ASCII backtick, `` ` ``; Powershell doesn't recognize a curly Unicode equivalent of that character.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try both when I’m back on my machine. Smart quotes didn’t seem to work for me.